# Raspberry Pi 2 booting only when HDMI is connected

Tags: boot, boot-issues

I have a Raspberry Pi 2, and when I connected an HDMI cable from my TV to the Pi, it boots, but when I try to boot without the HDMI cable, the green light flashes rapidly for a second or two, and then just stays on.

I have a WiFi dongle connected to a USB port, and the power light never goes on. I also can't ssh onto it. I have tried `rpi-update` and `apt-update` and `apt-upgrade`.

Comment: Can you ssh onto it with the hdmi cable plugged in?

Comment: Try adding `hdmi_force_hotplug=1`  to the `/boot/config.txt` file. Reboot the raspberry pi and then it should work from there.

Comment: "In normal circumstances there is NEVER a need to run rpi-update as it always gets you to the leading edge firmware and kernel and because that may be a testing version it could leave your RPi unbootable". https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=916911#p916911

Comment: "the power light never goes on" **WHICH** power light - on the Pi or WiFi dongle?